# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i have a json response in the following format i want to retrieve every "friend" in the json response and put it in an array in order to iterate it on HTML

Comment: `response.data.friend` returns a **single object**. Expect that you use `*ngFor` to iterate with `this.selectData.users` which `*ngFor` requires array or iterables as error mentioned. Unless you **cast `response.data.friend` to an array**.

Comment: you are getting object friends from backend and on that object you are expecting to loop a for loop. Loop can run on arrays and not objects you should check your backend and return array from there and not object then you will be able to iterate through it

Answer (score 0):

From the response you posted, the friend only contains a single object, like @Yongshun mentioned.

If your friend contains multiple object, you should change the backend API to return an array of objects:

```
{code: 200
data:
1:
created_at: ""
deleted_at: null
friend: [
        {id: 16, first_name: "Moses", last_name: "Johns",...},
        ...
    ]
}
```

Or if you want to iterator every properties of a single object, you should iterate over the object keys.

```
Object.keys(friend)
```